# Automatic buying and selling of created tokens not working. What am I missing?

Tags: solidity, ether, tokens

Created token using example code from etherum.org for automatic buying and selling but can't buy or sell from another account. What am I missing?

https://ethereum.org/token#automatic-selling-and-buying

**Update:**

I have transferred tokens to the contract from the owner wallet. This works.
I have set buy and sell prices.

How does any customer buy tokens from me using their Ether? The contract as it is won't allow ether to be sent to it.

If I need a to add a "fallback function" to the contract how is this done? Such a function is not in the example code so have ethereum.org stuffed up?

Why does this part of the contract not function as a fallback? Is it as simple as sending text with the ether transaction?

```
/// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether  
    function buy() payable public {  
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;        // calculates the amount  
        _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);       // makes the transfers  
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem you're having? any error message?

Comment: My contract had a buy() function but it won't accept ether. This is copied straight from the example provided by ethereum.org

Comment: Make sure you are sending enough gas with the `buy()` transaction. 200,000 should be a safe amount (the remainder/unused gas will be returned back to your wallet).

Comment: i need help to. Ive make a contect now it has cleared to testnet now i want to add a way to buy sell and exchange tokens for my token.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few things you have to take care of:

1. Make sure that there are some tokens at the token contract address.
   If there is not any, then noone is able to buy tokens, since every
   purchase is made not from the owner of the token but from the token
   contract address (`this`).

   If you have a look at the source code you linked you can see the
   line `Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount)` in the `buy` function.
   This means that the contract tries to send tokens from its own
   balance, but at the creation of the token contract, only the owner
   of the token contract possess tokens, not the contract itself. So just send some tokens from the owner of the contract to
   the token contract itself!
2. Did you set `buyPrice` and `sellPrice`? If you did not, then they are
   0, and division by zero will give you an exception at the `buy()`.

Comment: Thanks, great help! Brilliant stuff!. I had set prices but the contract itself did not have any tokens. When I try to send Ether to the contract it stills shows a  warning of a failed transaction error message. The "contract won't allow this transaction to be executed" for some reason. Please help me just a bit more if you can?

Comment: Do not send Ether to the token contract since it does not implement the fallback function, therefore the Ether transfer will always fail. Rather transfer tokens from the owner of the token contract to the token contract address. So you should do something like Token.transfer(Token Contract Address, amount). This transaction should be sent from the token owner account! Good luck!

Comment: Ok, Understood. I have transferred tokens to the contract from the owner contract. This works. 
How does any customer buy tokens from me using their Ether then? 
How do I add a "fallback function" to the contract? 

Why does this part of the contract not function as a fallback? Is it as simple as sending text with the ether?

/// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function buy() payable public {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;        // calculates the amount
        _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);        // makes the transfers
    }

Comment: 1) Buying tokens from the contract: they'll only need to call the buy() function and send some Ether along with this function call (transaction if you prefer). Note that only the buy function is 'payable' , so this is the only function which is able to accept Ether, all the rest will throw if you send Ether to it. 2) You can not add any function to your contract once it is deployed! The blockchain is immutable, therefore also your smart contract code! But you could redeploy a different token contract with some added functions if you'd like...

Comment: Yes understood, i would deploy a new contract as required to test with. But my existing contract had a buy() function. Why does it not accept ether?

Comment: How do I send " along with this function call (transaction if you prefer)"?

Comment: Buy  accepts Ether, since it is payable...If you use geth, you can send Ether with the transaction by setting the value field. Have a look here: https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/sending_ether.html You just need to modify this into eth.buy.sendTransaction()